# Reversal of HotEncoding without reducing columns to one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset which shows each transaction as a row.

for example;

| Item_1 | Item_2 | Item_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | NaN |

The table has 611 columns with 1180 rows, therefore 611 items and 1180 transactions.

I'm looking to do a basket analysis hence I need all rows which have '1' to be changed to the Item 'name'

For example...

| Item_1 | Item_2 | Item_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | Item_2 | Item_3 |
| Item_1 | Item_2 | NaN |

Then I aim to delete the header columns and just have each transaction on each row aligned without NaN's

i.e

| No_header | No_header | No_header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item_2 | Item_3 | NaN |
| Item_1 | Item_2 | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
items = df.apply(lambda col: col.map({1: col.name})).apply(lambda row: row[~row.isna()].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> items
0    [Item_2, Item_3]
1    [Item_1, Item_2]
dtype: object

>>> type(items)
pandas.core.series.Series
```